# Can't retrieve data from Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a view controller displaying information of the clicked shop from a UITableView on the previous view controller. However, I cannot retrieve data in the new view controller and I don't know how to solve this issue. Here is my database structure. Thank you for the help.
[image: Database Structure]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ShopViewController: UIViewController {    
    var name :String? // This is the name of the cell clicked on the previous viewcontroller

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    @IBOutlet weak var shopName: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var shopType: UILabel!    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        shopName.text = name

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("shops").childByAutoId().child(name!).child("Details")

        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in            
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
            let imageUrlString = snapshotValue["imageURL"] as! String
            print(imageUrlString)
            let shoptype = snapshotValue["type"] as! String
            self.shopType.text = shoptype            
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: the shop owner creates an account and adds their data which creates this data

Comment: Not yet sorry I will this evening and I'll comment back

Comment: Yes it works thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a couple of issues here, first off is your data structure.

Something along these lines would be much easier to read from. You shouldn't need the `name` field as far as I can tell, and is there a requirement to have the details nested?

[image]

### Reading the data

Next up, you can refactor your data reference code. I'd firstly recommend extracting the logic into its own method rather than having it directly in `viewDidLoad`:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    shopName.text = name
    self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    getShopDetails()
}

func getShopDetails() {
  guard let shopName = name else { return }
   ref.child("shops").child(shopName).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in         
        guard let shop = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

        let imageUrlString = shop["imageURL"] as! String
        print(imageUrlString)
        let shoptype = shop["type"] as! String
        self.shopType.text = shoptype            
    })
}
```

I've modified to set the database reference value as otherwise this would crash if you tried to use it elsewhere. I've also added a couple of guard statements to minimise the number of explicit unwraps.

I can't comment on your list code, but have you considered doing the call for all of the shops in this, and mapping the result to a data object, which you can then use to display the data in the screen we're detailing here, rather than doing a separate query every-time you open a detail screen.

Comment: return nil  gives the error 'Unexpected non-void return value in void function'

Comment: ah yeah sorry I reused my old code, change `return nil` to `return`

Answer (score 1):

The reference that you have is wrong, `childByAutoId()` is used to generate a unique id in your database.

Also the id that you currently have is the userid, you need to retrieve the userid:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let uid = user.uid
```

then the location should be:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("shops").child(uid).child("Eat").child("Details")
```